# Chrome extension - Refused to load the script '<URL>' because it violates the Content Security Policy

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've created a chrome extension that use firebase rtdb. It have worked fine until my last vue build where started to give this error in console

```
Refused to load the script '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback
```

I've tried to set hosts permissions in manifest v3 but not worked.

```js
import { defineManifest } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'

export default defineManifest({
  name: 'my-extension',
  description: '',
  version: '1.0.0',
  manifest_version: 3,
  icons: {
    16: 'img/logo-16.png',
    32: 'img/logo-34.png',
    48: 'img/logo-48.png',
    128: 'img/logo-128.png',
  },
  action: {
    default_icon: 'img/logo-48.png',
  },
  //options_page: 'options.html',
  background: {
    service_worker: 'src/background/index.js',
    type: 'module',
  },
  permissions: [
    'tabs'
  ],
  host_permissions: [
    'https://*.firebaseio.com'
  ]
})
```

How I can make firebase working again in my chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in manifest.json

```
{
"content_security_policy": {
"extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'",
"sandbox": "self"
  }
}
```

Read more at [content-security-policy](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy)

Comment: I've tried but the problem still persist. The only solution worked is to uninstall the extension and reinstall it. Not sure if this is a chrome bug or a problem with the manifest